# L'impact des rectifications orthographiques sur le participe passé du verbe « croitre » au féminin (crue) etc. : statu quo ou évolution ?

Tags: verbes, participe-passé, diacritiques, réforme-orthographique-1991, académie-française

> Selon la proposition du Conseil supérieur de la langue fr. [...],
>   l'accent circonflexe n'est maintenu sur la voyelle *u* que pour éviter
>   des homographies : il est donc supprimé sur *redu* et sur *mu*, mais
>   il est maintenu sur *dû, crû* et *recrû*, et, pour les deux derniers,
>   même ajouté au fém. et au plur. puisqu'ils seraient homographes du
>   fém. et du plur. des adjectifs *cru* (aussi participe de *croire*) et
>   *recru*. Malheureusement, **le texte de la proposition, tel qu'il a été imprimé, est moins clair que ce qui avait été décidé**. L'Acad.,
>   qui avait donné son approbation générale aux rectifications, n'en
>   parle pas à l'article *croitre*. Pour le part. passé, elle ne parle
>   pas du pluriel ; pour le fém., **elle ne le mentionnait pas en 1989**
>   et elle est revenue à *crue* depuis 1992.
>
> [ Le bon usage, Grevisse et Goosse, De Boeck/Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>,
>   §808 a), je souligne ]
>
> ---
>
> [Ac.8](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/cr%C3%BB) (1932) : *La rivière a crû, est crue.*
>  [Ac.9](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/cr%C3%BB)
>   (courant) : (*je croîs, nous croissons ; je croissais, nous croissions
>   ; je crûs ; je croîtrai ; je croîtrais ; croîs, croissons ; que je
>   croisse ; que je crûsse ; croissant ; crû, crue*).
>  [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%BB) : [...] Il
>   [l'accent circonflexe] est absent des formes *croissons, croissez,
>   croissent* et du part. passé au fém. et au plur. *crue, crus,
>   crues*. [...] 
>  [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=circonflexe&btn_chercher=CHERCHER&id=3166) (je souligne) : [...] L’accent circonflexe est
>   **maintenu** pour sa fonction analogique ou distinctive dans les masculins singuliers *dû, mûr* et *sûr*; dans *jeûne* et *jeûnes* (nom
>   ou verbe); dans les formes de *croitre* qui, sinon, se confondraient
>   avec celles de *croire*;  dans les terminaisons verbales du passé
>   simple (exemples : *nous finîmes, vous fûtes*) et dans les
>   terminaisons verbales du subjonctif (exemples : *qu’il ouvrît, qu’il
>   eût dormi*).

- Y a-t-il une raison particulière expliquant pourquoi l'accent circonflexe était traditionnellement absent du participe passé du verbe *croitre* au féminin et au pluriel ?
- Peut-on expliquer la différence dont parle le *LBU* entre ce qui avait été discuté et le texte imprimé de la proposition du Conseil supérieur de la langue française ?
- Dans quel cadre/où l'Académie ne mentionnait pas le pluriel en 1989 ?
- Le (non-)traitement dans *Ac.9* du participe passé en question au féminin (*crue*) et au pluriel est-il un type de traitement qui soit conforme à l'esprit et à la lettre des rectifications orthographiques de 1990 ; n'y a-t-il pas homographie avec le participe passé de *croire* (*cru(e)*) ainsi qu'avec l'adjectif *cru(e)* ; l'idée de « maintenir » à la BDL signifie-t-elle que l'OQLF soit du même avis que l'Académie française à cet effet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Y a-t-il une raison particulière expliquant pourquoi l'accent
>   circonflexe était traditionnellement absent du participe passé du
>   verbe croitre au féminin et au pluriel ?

La raison de cela est toute simple : Ces formes fléchies du participe passé n'existent (*traditionnellement*) pas!

De fait, dans un emploi régulier et hors licence poétique (1), le verbe *croître* est rigoureusement intransitif (2) (=> pas de COD) et se conjugue avec l'auxiliaire avoir.

Dans ces conditions, il n'existe rigoureusement aucune construction grammaticale, aucune phrase dans laquelle le participe passé doive être accordé avec un sujet ou un objet direct.
Pas plus de féminin que de pluriel et donc encore moins de féminin-pluriel, **le participe passé est rigoureusement invariable.** (3)

---

<sup>1 : "*Que pour croître à la fois sa gloire et mon tourment*" (Racine)</sup>

<sup>2: Le DHLF observe un usage transitif *"anciennement toléré"* qui a disparu au XIIIe au profit d'*accroître*.</sup>

<sup>3 : à lépoque où on a décidé des conjugaisons.</sup>

---

Toute la suite de l'histoire ne retraduit qu'un petit flottement (bien légitime) lié à la considération du bien fondé / de la réalité / de la fréquence de l'usage transitif pour décider si une correction est nécessaire, quel mot va la porter, ou... s'il est urgent d'attendre.

---

Pour en finir par la question du titre : Il semble très probable que concurrencé déjà bien largement par *accroître, augmenter, (a)grandir,...* l'usage de croitre au sens transitif va se restreindre et ainsi prolonger le statu quo pour... au moins... un certain temps avec le strict minimum de préjudice.